# Include the splitting pattern/token from scala regex.split()

Tags: regex, scala

The `scala.util.matching.Regex` appears to only have a single `split()` method whose behavior is to extract the match and return only the non-matching segments of the input string:

```
val str = "Here is some stuff PAT and second token PAT and third token PAT and fourth"
val r = "PAT".r
r.split(str)

res14: Array[String] = Array("Here is some stuff ", " and second token ", "
and third token ", " and fourth")
```

So is there another approach commonly used to retain the tokens in the returned list?

Note: the splitting patterns I use for actual work are somewhat complicated and certainly not constants like the above example. Therefore, simply inserting alternating constant values (or zipping them) would not suffice.

**Update**  Here is a more representative regex

```
val str = "Here is some stuff PAT and second token PAT and third token 
           or something else and fourth"
val r = "(PAT|something else)".r
r.split(str)

res14: Array[String] = Array("Here is some stuff ", " and second token ", "
and third token ", " and fourth")
```

Comment: How complicated is the pattern? If it is not, then a mere [`val r = "((?<=PAT)|(?=PAT))".r`](http://ideone.com/8bqBCR) could help.

Comment: @stribizhev  Well I need to put character classes in there. Your comment is already interesting (so pls add as answer) . I am checking if it were actually sufficient to completely satisfy the need.

Comment: @stribizhev  I updated the OP. Your suggestion DOES work - even for the expanded scope. Please create an answer - and maybe add a little explanation with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a non-complicated pattern that does not involve patterns of indefinite width, you can use a lookbehind/lookahead solution:

```
val str = "Here is some stuff PAT and second token PAT and third token PAT and fourth"
val r = "((?<=PAT)|(?=PAT))".r
print(r.split(str).toList)
```

Output of the [sample demo](http://ideone.com/8bqBCR): `List(Here is some stuff , PAT,  and second token , PAT,  and third token , PAT,  and fourth)`

The idea is just to match the empty strings before `(?<=PAT)` and after `(?=PAT)` the `PAT` pattern, and only split there. Unfortunately, there is no such a handy feature as split using a regex with a capturing group and keep the captured text as an element of the resulting array/list.

As an alternative, the *matching* regex with `findAllIn` should be used. Or temporary one-character delimiters in front or end of the delimiting pattern can be created to further split against them.